# Como modificar tela padrão zxing

Tags: android, biblioteca

Boa noite,

Eu integrei o zxing ao meu app usando esse tutorial:
https://android-coffee.com/tutorial-how-to-create-barcode-reader-app-in-android-studio-1-4/

Deu certo, mas para que funcionasse pediu que eu instalasse o app do zxing e quando seleciono o botão de scan, sou redirecionado para o app.

Gostaria de saber se tem como integrar essa funcionalidade ao meu aplicativo, sem ser necessário instalar outro app (acho que isso pode ser um pouco incômodo para o usuário).
Outra alternativa para meu problema seria pelo menos acrescentar alguns botões na tela

[image: Tela padrão Zxing]

Essa foto é da tela padrão do zxing e queria acrescentar dois botões e mudar a orientação.

Se alguem já tiver mexido com essa biblioteca peço que me ajude, até encontrei alguns tutoriais de integração mas achei muito complexo e não sei se vai trazer o resultado que quero no final.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [**Barcode API**](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview) do **[Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/)** que é do próprio Google. Se você sente incomodado que as pessoas vão se sentir incomodadas, você pode dar uma estudada melhor na documentação e fazer a implementação direto da sua aplicação. E sim, talvez seja um pouco complexo por se tratar de "tratamento de imagem", porém você tem um controle maior para customização.

Para iniciar um projeto, veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0).

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, valeu!